# Why the api call that works with HTTParty doesn't with Faraday?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

The following is the API call to a remote service that executes successfully when I use with HTTParty.

```
require 'httparty'

class TheAPI
  include HTTParty
  base_uri 'https://someapp.com'
  # headers  "Content-Type" => "application/json"

  def self.create_job
    post( '/jobs.json', :query => {:apikey => "kOrROwbVPNC34VZYhbET", :job => {:method => "PUT", :at => '2012-01-31T18:36:21', :uri => "http://kasko.com"}})
  end
end

puts TheAPI.create_job
```

But when I try to make the same call using Faraday, I get this unknown error:

```
require 'faraday_stack'

conn = Faraday.new 'https://someapp.com', ssl: {verify: false} do |builder|
  builder.use   FaradayStack::ResponseJSON,     content_type: 'application/json'
  builder.use   Faraday::Response::Logger#,      Logger.new('faraday.log')
  # builder.use FaradayStack::FollowRedirects,  limit: 3
  builder.use Faraday::Response::RaiseError   # raise exceptions on 40x, 50x responses
  builder.use   Faraday::Adapter::NetHttp
end

# conn.headers[:user_agent] = 'MyLib v1.2'

resp = conn.post "jobs.json", {:apikey => "kOrROwbVPNC34VZYhbET", :job => {:method => "PUT", :at => '2012-01-31T18:36:21', :uri => "http://kasko.com"}}
puts resp
```

The error raised is:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method ‘bytesize’ for #<Hash:0x000001011ab8f8>

method send_request_with_body   in http.rb at line 1735
method exec in http.rb at line 1724
method transport_request    in http.rb at line 1189
method request  in http.rb at line 1177
method block in request in http.rb at line 1170
method start    in http.rb at line 627
method request  in http.rb at line 1168
method call in net_http.rb at line 51
method call in response.rb at line 8
method call in response.rb at line 8
method call in logger.rb at line 20
method call in response.rb at line 8
method run_request  in connection.rb at line 203
method post in connection.rb at line 90
method <main>   in test.rb at line 33
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using [mislav's recent blog post about Faraday](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2011/07/faraday-advanced-http/) for a code sample. You'll notice that in his example, the code you used is only being used for a GET request, not a POST request. When he made a POST request earlier in the page, he set a specific `Faraday::Request` type.

Based on the discussion at [github](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday/issues/69), [moment](http://momentapp.com/docs) requires that you post JSON data, so you need to use this:

```
builder.use Faraday::Request::JSON
```

Comment: i've added the comment at its github issues https://github.com/technoweenie/faraday/issues/69